# Finding the differences between 2 files in nodejs

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I have 2 json files which have static data.

File A.json

```
{
"data": ["A","B","C","D"]
}
```

File B.json

```
{
"data":["A","B","C"]
}
```

Now I want find the difference between these two files.

I tried using this code to get files by its name

```
const express = require("express");
const jsonfile = require("jsonfile");
const app = express();
const fs  = require("fs");

app.use(express.json());

const BASEPATH = "./data"

app.get("/api/v1/data/:name", async (req,res) =>  {
const fileName = req.params.name;
const filePath = `${BASEPATH}/${fileName}.json`
try {
    const readData = await jsonfile.readFile(filePath);
    res.status(200).json(readData);
}catch (e) {
    res.status(404).send(e);
}
});
```

The URL is : localhost:3000/api/v1/data/A

To add data I used,

```
app.put("/api/v1/data",(req,res) => {
const fileName = req.body.name;
const data = req.body.data;

const filePath = `${BASEPATH}/${fileName}.json`

fs.exists(filePath, async exists => {
    if(exists) {
        try {
            await jsonfile.writeFile(filePath,{data:data});
            res.status(200).send();
        }catch(e) {
            res.send(500).json(e);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            await jsonfile.writeFile(filePath,{data:data});
            res.status(201).send();
        }catch(e) {
            res.send(500).json(e);
        }
    }
})
});
```

Example of added data:

```
{ "name":"C", "data":["A","B","Z"]}
```

URL is: localhost:3000/api/v1/data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this,

```
app.get("/api/v1/data/diff", async (req,res) => {
try {
    const file1 = req.query.file1;
    const file2 = req.query.file2;
    console.log(file1,file2)
    if(file1 === undefined || file2 === undefined ) {
        res.status(401).send("BAD REQUEST. SEND FILE NAMES");
        return;   
    } else {
        const filePath1 = `${BASEPATH}/${file1}.json`
        const filePath2 = `${BASEPATH}/${file2}.json`

        const file1Data = await jsonfile.readFile(filePath1);
        const file2Data = await jsonfile.readFile(filePath2);

        let difference = file1Data.data.filter(x => !file2Data.data.includes(x));
        let difference2 = file2Data.data.filter(x => !file1Data.data.includes(x));

        res.status(200).json({diff: [...difference,...difference2]});
    }
}catch(e) {
    res.status(500).json(e);
}
});
```

you have to use the url like : localhost:3000/api/v1/data/diff?file1=A&file2=B

the output will be

{
     "diff": [
        "D"
     ]
   }